# Defining a broader scope of on-topic questions

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Given the site being relatively new there are many (and will be eve more) questions like :

> Are questions on topic X is - on-topic or off-topic?

Here are some glimps:

[Computer Vision questions are on-topic or off-topic?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63/computer-vision-questions-are-on-topic-or-off-topic)
[Are OpenCV questions on topic?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/are-opencv-questions-on-topic)
[Are questions on numerical analysis on-topic?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36/are-questions-on-numerical-analysis-on-topic)
[Is this the place for Neuroscience related questions?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/is-this-the-place-for-neuroscience-related-questions)
[Do hardware benchmarks questions have lasting value?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93/do-hardware-benchmarks-questions-have-lasting-value)
[Where do PID loop + other control systems questions go?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143/where-do-pid-loop-other-control-systems-questions-go)

I think it is best that we organize a sort of rather longer *a prior list* of what we think is on-topic or off-topic right away. Over time we can edit this as well, but we can find one central place that keeps definition refining all throughout.

Comment: Yeah, those are important points. I would also add that sometimes is tempting to ask the same question on multiple domains because they can be viewed as different types of problems.

Comment: Given that Claude Shannon seemed to consider himself in the field of signal processing, will the community consider the broad range of information theory questions as on-topic?  I've found that those with backgrounds in signal processing will often have clearer insights to broader information theory questions than more general mathematicians or statisticians.  Just wondering.

Comment: @Jagra I think that's worth bringing up. Feel free to start a meta question about it.

Answer (score 1):

**Computer Vision**

I believe it is on-topic:

- it uses image processing techniques
- it can be interpreted as video processing (video should be signal, right? :) )
- [Computer Vision proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11036/computer-vision) from Area51 is now officially *closed*, with most of the questions redirected to this site

**OpenCV**

The linked meta question from the question gives the [right answer](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/106/1273):

- *programming questions*: off-topic
- *how something works*: on-topic

Some of my taughts:

- If OpenCV is the language of choice, looking for *a direction or a technique that utilized OpenCV tools* (implemented algorithms etc.) **is okay**, *requesting a new or debugged code* **is not**
- When explaining the output of OpenCV code, explaining an output of erroneous code is **off-topic**, but explaining unexpected or interesting results (e.g. cornercase inputs) might be okay - although there is a fine line here

I also believe that a **similar rule** should stand for all the *data structures*, *widely-accepted tools* (Matlab, OpenCV...) and other *principles*:

> If it is about applying it to process signals (images, audio, video, and everything else ppl do here) than it's okay. A general-concept questions about how something works, how it can be used and when it can be applied are okay, questions requesting large working amounts of code are not.

It is pretty obvious from my answer what my topics of research are, but I hope it is still applicable.

Answer (score 0):

**Computer Vision**

I believe that computer vision should be considered on-topic here for two reasons: (i) sometimes it is very hard to separate this topic from digital image processing and (ii) there's no specific site for it.

**OpenCV**

OpenCV is an important tool for digital image processing and I believe that it should be considered on-topic.